# Calling two HttpStatusCode.Created at the same line in asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my POST method in a Controller.cs, I have been writing only a single value into the database so far, so at the end I returned the status of the response with the following code:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse<object>(HttpStatusCode.Created, iconOffset);
return response;
```

But now, I am writing two values into the database, and I would love to return the status of both at the end of the POST method, how do I do that? I tried the following:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse<object>(HttpStatusCode.Created, HttpStatusCode.Created, iconOffset, tempOffset);
return response;
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't return multiple http status codes to the browser.

You make a request for something, you get a response back - that response was either `OK` or another status code, there's no concept of multiple response codes.

If you need to elaborate with your response, return a `model` along with your status for whatever is consuming the endpoint, one example would be:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new DatabaseUpdateResult(results));
```

If your application could accept/return json, then this could be consumed by the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The response code is the HTTP response code and there is only one. You could either split out the method into two endpoints or return a status that represents the state of the operation.

Your client should have no knowledge of what is going on behind the service (database, services, ...) so if you're posting something to that endpoint and semantically it gets created just return Created. If an error occurs you could return InternalServerError.

Here's a list of HTTP status codes you can use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes